# Phonegap + AngularJS - back button behavior

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been trying to override Android's back button in my AngularJS application for a few hours and I just can't do it. I've been able to make the back button stop from working, but I can't make it go back or even make it go to the home page. I'm not using routes - instead, I'm simply switching the page so I'm not even sure it's possible to go back. If I could go to the home page It'd be great. Here's my code:

```
  var onDeviceReady = function(){
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleDeviceBackButton, false);
}
function handleDeviceBackButton(){
  angular.element('[ng-controller=AppCtrl]').scope().goHome();
  menu.setMainPage('home.html', {closeMenu: true});
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only need to go back use

```
$window.history.back();
```

---

However, I suggest you use a routing solution like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Using $state, navigation is simpler:

```
$state.go('home');
```

Instead of adding an event listener via PhoneGap you can rely on browser back button. Your app is a webpage so triggering back button on Android will go back in your [history state](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/History). Avoiding device events allows you to debug your code right in the desktop browser.

If you want to block a specific back state or do a redirect you would use:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
   if (from.name == "splashscreen" && to.name =="home"){
     //redirect using navigation $state service
   }
});
```